# Modify a generated Biblatex file to add extra fields (post processing)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, zotero, bibtool

The reference manager I use (Zotero), does not support certain fields which I want to use (e.g. DOI for book selection).

Is there some tool to automatically add a field + value to a certain BibTex key? So every time I export from Zotero, my build process will inject extra fields.

So I am looking for something like this:

```
cat myBibliography.bib | BibTexAddFieldTool -keyId Author_2015 -fieldId doi -value "MyDOI" > newMyBibliography.bib
```

Comment: Not posting this as an answer bc it doesn't directly address your question, but you could also, with relative ease, add these to Zotero, e.g. in the extra field with a new line for every new field and then modify Zotero's bib(la)tex export to include them.

Specifically for DOIs, if you include them in the form `DOI: 10.123/4567`, Zotero would very likely even auto-convert them once the field is included for chapters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really a *TeX answer, but you can write a small script in any programming language of your choice, for example perl (for demonstration purposes only, i.e., regexes not robust, adjust to Zotero output or use some proper key-value pair library):

```perl
open(BIB,"<$ARGV[0]");
open(XTR,"<$ARGV[1]");
while($line=<BIB>){
    if($line=~/^\s*@(.*?){\s*(.*),\s*$/){   #% read BibTeX key
        $key = $2;
        $type{$key}=$1;
    }
    if($line=~/^\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*?),?\s*$/){   #% store field values for key
        $val{$key}{$1}=$2;
    }
}
while($line=<XTR>){
    if($line=~/^(.*?),(.*?),(.*)$/){   #% store additional fields
        $val{$1}{$2}=$3;
    }
}
foreach $key(sort keys %val){   #% print everything to stdout
    print "@".$type{$key}."{$key,\n";
    foreach $field (sort keys %{$val{$key}}){
        print "\t$field\t=\t$val{$key}{$field},\n";
    }
    print "}\n\n";
}
```

Usage: `perl BibTexAddFieldTool.pl myBibliography.bib myAddedFields.txt`

Sample bibliography:

```
@book{chicken:2010fj,
    author = {Chicken, C},
    title = {Chicken},
    publisher = {Chicken Press},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{lemur:2009ii,
    author = {Lemur, L},
    title = {Lemur},
    publisher = {Lemur Press},
    year = {2009}
}
```

Additional fields:

```
chicken:2010fj,doi,{12345}
lemur:2009ii,doi,{54321}
lemur:2009ii,title,{Lemur Adventures}
```

Output:

```
@book{chicken:2010fj,
    author  =   {Chicken, C},
    doi =   {12345},
    publisher   =   {Chicken Press},
    title   =   {Chicken},
    year    =   {2010},
}

@book{lemur:2009ii,
    author  =   {Lemur, L},
    doi =   {54321},
    publisher   =   {Lemur Press},
    title   =   {Lemur Adventures},
    year    =   {2009},
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I could write something like this myself, however I was wondering a 'standard' solution is available for this or not.

Comment: perl has a `Text::BibTeX` module which is what biber uses internally too. This can read, modify and write .bib files quickly with full semantic control.